# Webrtc audio level goes crazy randomly

Tags: webrtc, pulseaudio

I have a remote Webrtc endpoint (based on libwebrtc) that produces audio from a pulseaudio sink monitor. I can successfully consume it in Chrome via a video html tag. The problem that I am facing is that the audio seems to go "crazy" randomly, meaning that the audio level suddenly goes very high and it's impossible to listen to it.

On the sending side, I am using this to disable audio processing:

```
cricket::AudioOptions options;    
options.highpass_filter = false;
options.auto_gain_control = false;
options.noise_suppression = false;
options.echo_cancellation = false;
options.residual_echo_detector = false;
options.experimental_agc = false;
options.experimental_ns = false;
options.typing_detection = false;
rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::AudioSourceInterface> source = webrtcFactory->CreateAudioSource(options);
```

But on the receiving side (Chrome browser), there seems to be no way to disable it.

Running ***mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()*** in Chrome returns:

```
aspectRatio: true
autoGainControl: true
brightness: true
channelCount: true
colorTemperature: true
contrast: true
deviceId: true
echoCancellation: true
exposureCompensation: true
exposureMode: true
exposureTime: true
facingMode: true
focusDistance: true
focusMode: true
frameRate: true
groupId: true
height: true
iso: true
latency: true
noiseSuppression: true
pointsOfInterest: true
resizeMode: true
sampleRate: true
sampleSize: true
saturation: true
sharpness: true
torch: true
whiteBalanceMode: true
width: true
zoom: true
```

Then running ***track.getCapabilities()*** in Chrome returns:

```
autoGainControl: [false]
deviceId: "7254143d-7c85-4567-9d95-94f2c79060fe"
echoCancellation: [false]
noiseSuppression: [false]
sampleSize: {max: 16, min: 16}
```

And finally ***track.getConstraints()*** in Chrome returns and empty object.

What I understand from the above is that Chrome supports audio processing cancellation, but the track does not. At this moment I am confused regarding as to at which point (sending or receiving) webrtc's audio processing makes the sound level go crazy.

I've read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/-ACwaFI7jWQ) that (when using a file as test input in Chrome) "***all audio processing has to be disabled or the audio will be distorted***". Which is exactly what I want to do for my track as well, with the difference being that since my track is remote, I am not obtaining it via the browser's *getUserMedia()*.

I have been reading a lot about disabling Webrtc's audio processing and trying various things both on the producing and consuming side, but the same problem still appears randomly.

Do you have any idea on which side (sender or Chrome consumer) the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the sending side, and unrelated to libwebrtc.